# MongodDB print result when assign variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have two collections, I would like to assign two querty to variable:

```
okbooks = db.downloaded_book_status.find({status:"OK"}).count()
errorbooks = db.downloaded_book_status.find({status:"ERROR"}).count()
```

and then print

```
result = 'OK:'+okbooks+' | ERROR:'+errorbooks
```

but each time when I assign variable proces print query result. I wanna print only result. If it is any possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
okbooks = db.downloaded_book_status.count({status:"OK"})
errorbooks = db.downloaded_book_status.count({status:"ERROR"})
```

Comment: It also print result:
> okbooks = db.downloaded_book_status.count({status:"OK"})
68932
> errorbooks = db.downloaded_book_status.count({status:"ERROR"})
1709

Answer (score 0):

Finally I change it to:

```
result = 'OK:'+db.downloaded_book_status.find({status:"OK"}).count()
+' | ERROR:'+db.downloaded_book_status.find({status:"ERROR"}).count()
```

Rather than pass variable I pass query.